# If $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=L$, prove that $|a_n|>\frac{L}{2}$ for some $n>n_0$

Tags: real-analysis

I have to prove that if $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n=L$, then there exists $N_0$ such that $|a_n|>\frac{L}{2}$ for all $n\geq N_0$. Intuitively, it is obvious but I have a very hard time writing a formal proof. My idea was to say that since $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n=L$, for all $n>N_0$, $|a_n|\approx|L|$ and $|L|>|\frac{L}{2}|\geq\frac{L}{2}$. Therefore, there exists some $N_0$ such that $|a_n|\approx|L|>|\frac{L}{2}|\geq\frac{L}{2}$ for all $n>N_0$, so there exists some $N_0$ such that $|a_n|>\frac{L}{2}$ for all $n>N_0$. Is there any way to make the proof more formal?

Comment: Use the limit definition. What $\epsilon$ do you need to take? Start with examples: e.g. for $L=10$, what $\epsilon$ will do? How about for $L=2$? And for $L=1$? Then write the general $\epsilon$ for a general $L$.

Comment: It's not true without more assumptions.  Did you want to assume $L\neq 0$, for instance?  Either that or allow for $|a_n|=\frac L2$.

Comment: I was also confused about the case when $L=0$ but there are no more assumptions in the question

Comment: Well, the claim is not always true when $L=0$.  Consider the case with all the $a_n=0$, for instance.

Comment: Yes, that solved it, thank you very much! I have to bring up the problem with the assumptions in the class